# Default value added in select option using jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3

```
var options = data.map(function(el) {
return `<option value="${el.id}">${el.id}</option>`;
});
```

How can I add Default value for option like this ---Select--- before displaying id.

Comment: after map statement add `options.unshift('--Select--');`

Comment: Where I want to insert this line with in return statement or before the return statement

Comment: then add the desired option at beginning of `data` array.

Comment: In data array I got a dropdown value from db like this  var data=<?php echo json_encode($employee);?>; so how can I add the option tag as you told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allowed to use ES6, then the simplest solution is using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
data = [{id:'--Select--'},...data];
```

Your problem can be solved by just appending `select` to data.

```
var data=<?php echo json_encode($employee);?>;
data.unshift({id:'--Select--'});
```